# If Budha is avatar of Vishnu, why he created Buddhism?

Tags: gods

Why Lord Budha did not follow Lord Krishna if they both are Lord Vishnu avatars.

Why they both came up with different paths.Did Budha opposed Bhagavadgeeta ?

Comment: There are various Buddhas. It depends on which Buddha you are talking about. Besides AFAIK  Buddha approved Vedas as authoritative in some difficult situations where no explanation is possible otherwise.

Comment: In order to confuse the asura-natured humans. They were using vedic mantras to gain power. So he tricked them into disbelieving Vedas. But he still gave them a moral path so they could become good. Once they become good, then they'll get birth in a religion that does believe in Vedas, so that they use the power of Veda mantras for good.

Comment: He was not avatar of vishnu

Answer (score 0):

It is a misconception that  goutham Buddha is 9th avatar of sri vishnu. Reality is  mahaprabhu Jagannath is the 9th avatar  or buddha avatar because buddha means  sense in immovable, brahma as soul in a static form of god, unchanged, steadfast and lord jagannath has all these formations. Adi sankarcharya also knew it that's why he established 4 sakarchary muth in 4 places in which puri jaganath ia one of them. One rama avatar-rameswar, one krishna - dwarka, narsingh-badrinath, buddha jagannath - puri